# On an ASA 5505 can you setup Site to Site VPN's as well as Anyconnect or IPSEC VPN's at the same time

Tags: vpn, cisco-asa, cisco-vpn

I have an ASA 5505 with 3 site-to-site vpn's configured and working.  I also want to setup a remote access vpn, either using the AnyConnect wizard or just an IPSEC VPN (again using the wizard) to use the Windows 10 VPN client (which works) using the same ASA.  However, when I setup the IPSEC or AnyConnect VPN, I lost connection to my site-to-site vpn's.  So it seems like I can have one or the other but not both. Is this true or is there some trick that i'm missing, or isn't available when using the ASDM to configure?

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: You can definitely have site-to-site and remote access VPN in parallel. If you need help troubleshooting then please add the non-working config to the question.

Comment: Hi Hertitu, you were right...not sure what we were doing wrong originally but I was able to get both types of vpn functional and setup with split-tunneling.  Thanks for the help